# Hi is it possible to create an entity in Dialogflow using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

I'm  trying to create an entity on Dialogflow using Node.js. Is it possible? If yes, how should I execute it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. For reference see [EntityTypesClient()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow/latest/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.EntityTypes.html) for other methods you can use regarding entities.

Prior to executing the code, make sure you have done the following as mentioned in [Dialogflow nodejs quickstart](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow#before-you-begin).

1. Select or create a Cloud Platform project.
2. Enable billing for your project.
3. Enable the Dialogflow API API.
4. Set up authentication with a service account so you can access the API from your local workstation.

The code example below creates an entity **test_sizing** with a value that have corresponding synonyms. You can also print values of `response` if you need information from it.

```
'use strict';

const dialogflow = require('@google-cloud/dialogflow');

const entityClient = new dialogflow.EntityTypesClient();
const agentPath = entityClient.projectAgentPath('your-project-id-here');
const entityType = {
        displayName: 'test_sizing',
        kind: 'KIND_MAP',
        entities: [
        {value: 'small', synonyms: ['small', 'petit']},
        {value: 'medium', synonyms: ['medium']},
        {value: 'large', synonyms: ['large', 'big']},
      ],
};
const request = { parent: agentPath, entityType: entityType };
const response = entityClient.createEntityType(request);
```

---

**Dialogflow output:**

[image]

**test_sizing entity:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to create entity types on Dialogflow [CX](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs) and [ES](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs).

Depending on the Dialogflow Edition you are using, you can use one of the following Node.js client libraries:

- **Dialogflow CX** - [@google-cloud/dialogflow-cx](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow-cx/latest/index.html)
- **Dialogflow ES/Trial** - [@google-cloud/dialogflow](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow/latest/index.html)

Both client libraries have an `EntityTypeClient` class which you can use to manage entity types. For your use case, you can use the `EntityTypeClient.createEntityType()` class method to create entity types.

Below are sample codes for creating entity types for each Dialogflow editions using the Node.js client libraries:

**Dialogflow CX:**

```
const {EntityTypesClient} = require('@google-cloud/dialogflow-cx');

const client = new EntityTypesClient()

async function createEntityType(projectId, location, agentId, language, displayName, entities, kind) {

    parent = client.agentPath(projectId, location, agentId)

    let entityType = {
        displayName,
        entities,
        kind
    }

    let request = {
        parent,
        entityType,
        language
    }

    const [response] = await client.createEntityType(request);
    console.log(response)
}

projectId = "<PROJECT_ID>"
location = "<LOCATION>"
agentId = "<AGENT_ID>" 
language = "<LANGUAGE_CODE>" 
displayName = "size" 
kind = "KIND_MAP" 
entities = [                  
    {
        value:"Small",
        synonyms:[
            "Small",
            "S"
        ]
    },
    {
        value:"Medium",
        synonyms:[
            "Medium",
            "M"
        ]
    }
]

createEntityType(projectId, location, agentId, language, displayName, entities, kind)
```

Result:

[image]

**Method reference:** [google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3.EntityTypeClient.createEntityType()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow-cx/latest/v3.EntityTypesClient.html#createEntityType)

**Dialogflow ES/Trial:**

```
const {
    EntityTypesClient
} = require('@google-cloud/dialogflow');

const client = new EntityTypesClient()

async function createEntityType(projectId, language, displayName, entities, kind) {

    parent = client.projectAgentPath(projectId)

    let entityType = {
        displayName,
        entities,
        kind
    }

    let request = {
        parent,
        entityType,
        language
    }

    const [response] = await client.createEntityType(request);
    console.log(response)
}

projectId = "<PROJECT_ID>"
language = "<LANGUAGE_CODE>"

displayName = "size"
kind = "KIND_MAP"
entities = [{
        value: "Small",
        synonyms: [
            "Small",
            "S"
        ]
    },
    {
        value: "Medium",
        synonyms: [
            "Medium",
            "M"
        ]
    }
]

createEntityType(projectId, language, displayName, entities, kind)
```

Result:

[image]

**Method reference:** [google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.EntityTypeClient.createEntityType()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow/latest/v2.EntityTypesClient.html#createEntityType)