# DialogFlow CX API, How to create entities under an existing entity type with nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client, dialogflow-cx

How can I create entities under an existing entity type with the DialogFlow CX API using nodejs?

I have already looked at [this question],([Hi is it possible to create an entity in Dialogflow using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68341093/hi-is-it-possible-to-create-an-entity-in-dialogflow-using-node-js)) however the answers can't add entities to an existing entity type. "Error: 6 ALREADY_EXISTS: com.google.apps.framework.request.AlreadyExistsException"